# How can I show the person who has generated the task in a column of the task list?

Tags: tasks, task-list, approval-process, approval

I need to show in a field, the name of the person who has generated the task, either because he has approved the previous task or because he has delegated the task producing the new one.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to Modify View on the Task List menu and add Created by.

Comment: In my case, the Created By field always indicates the same user as the user who uploaded the document that caused the workflow to start. Is there any other way to do this?